# How to Connect MySQL database to AFS server

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, database, remote-server

I have a python code that scrapes real-time data from yahoo finance (using finance library), then I convert it into a Dataframe and now I need to store this data into a MySQL table using (sqlalchemy library) The code is running perfectly fine in my laptop and it is storing data in the desired table on my local system. Now, I am running this code on AFS remote server (I don't know how many of you are familiar with AFS, it is a remote server which universities use). Now, the problem that I am facing is I cannot set up a MySQL server on AFS, or I cannot connect MySQL to AFS. Here's my code-

````
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from pandas.io import sql
import sys 
from sys import argv 
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import requests

link = "link from where the ticker list is taken"
f = requests.get(link)
ticker= f.text
ticker= ticker.strip('[]').split('\n')
ticker= list(filter(None, ticker))    
data= yf.download(tickers= ticker,period= '1d',interval='1m',group_by='Ticker') 
column_list = data.columns
comp_list = list(set([clm[0] for clm in column_list]))
temp_df = data[comp_list[0]]
temp_df.insert(0,'Ticker','')
temp_df['Ticker'] = comp_list[0]
for comp_name in comp_list[1:]:
    new_df = data[comp_name]
    new_df['Ticker'] = comp_name
    temp_df = pd.concat([temp_df, new_df], axis=0)
final_data = temp_df.reset_index()
final_data=final_data.sort_values(by='Datetime',ascending=False)
final_data= final_data.dropna()
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://username:password@localhost/database')
pandas_sql = pd.io.sql.pandasSQL_builder(engine)
final_data.to_sql('stocks',con=engine,
                  if_exists='replace',index=False)
print('task_done')```


#Please help me connect MySQL to AFS and save the data in a database table. Any leads would be appreciated.
````

Comment: AFS meaning "Andrew" or "Apple"?

Comment: If this is a question on how to set up MySQL server on AFS then this Python code is irrelevant. I'm also not sure that's a supported config for MySQL so you should check the documentation more closely.